# CodeIgniter encrypt decode not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I was using CodeIgniter encrypt library and everything was working fine, but now I've moved the project to a new server and it simple stoped working.

This simple test:

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$str = '12345';
$key = 'my-secret-key';
$encrypted = $this->encrypt->encode($str, $key);
var_dump($encrypted);
var_dump($this->encrypt->decode($encrypted, $key));
die();
```

Its returning:

```
string(76) "v9kMgDy+MUHgu5ug6N2qWms0/6tJ+a9N86kmpNvwkKI4nU8yL93kkAH1bmhn57ADh8WGB64i18E="
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mcrypt_decrypt(): Received initialization vector of size 38, but size 32 is required for this encryption mode

Filename: libraries/Encrypt.php

Line Number: 346

string(0) ""
```

(The PHP Error/Warning appears only sometimes)

Thanks

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: You really should not be using `$this->load->library('encrypt');`. Use `$this->load->library('encryption');` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use an exact length key (128, 192 or 256 bit for AES and an an exact length IV (128-bits or 16-bytes for AES), otherwise you will get an error or some unknown padding will be added.

The error is quite clear:

> Received initialization vector of size 38, but size 32 is required for this encryption mode

The IV is an incorrect length.

Of course there is the issue that the provided code does not have an IV.

Also the error messages states the expected IV length is 32 bytes, that is not AES. Mose likely it is Rijndael with a 256-bit key. This is a common error using mcrypt where the argument is the block size not the key size.  The key size is based on the size of the passed key.

`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is Rijndael with a 256-bit block size which **is not** AES,
`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` is Rijndael with a 128-bit block size which **is** AES